# Find index element in a list of lists and strings

Tags: python, indexing

I have a list containing strings and lists. Something like:

```
l = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e']
```

I need to find the index of an element I'm looking for in this nested list. For instance, if I need to find `c`, the function should return `2`, and if I'm looking for `d`, it should return `2` too. Consider that I have to do this for a large number of elements. Before I was simply using

```
idx = list.index(element)
```

but this does not work anymore, because of the nested lists. I cannot simply flatten the list, as I then shall use the index in another list with the same shape as this one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Will all the elements overall present in the given list be **unique**?

Comment: Of course not!!

Comment: @waqasgard You can't say that, OP must clarify.

Comment: @BishalGautam Hi. Well, hopefully they will be.

Comment: if l = ['a', 'c', ['c', 'd'], 'e'], what will you return 1 or 2 for 'c'?

Comment: In that case, probably 1.

Comment: @BishalGautam Generally, `.index()` gets the index of the **first** occurrence.

Comment: @sensitive_scientist, What should return if not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach, Iterating the list.

**Ex:**

```
l = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e']
toFind = "c"
toFind1 = "d"

for i, v in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        if toFind1 in v:
            print(i)
    else:
        if toFind1 == v:
            print(i)
```